# Como empujar nuevos elementos a un objeto en PHP ó Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, array-bidimensional

dentro de cada arreglo hay un objeto, en general estoy trabajando con Php & Larvel, y ocupo de meter los resultados del 2do arreglo(**Users** a **Questions**) en el primero, al final puse la manera en que espero tener los datos ;

- Intente de esta manera, para ingresar la clave, valor al arreglo **questions**, pero me aparecía un error:

  `*Cannot use object of type stdClass as array*`

  `$questions[0]["firstname"] = $user[1]->firstname`
- Despues intente quitando el indice al inicio de `$questions` y funcionó pero lo empujó como un índice nuevo, no dentro de l objeto que ya existe:

  `$questions["firstname"] = $user[1]->firstname`
- Use tambien `*array_push()*` & `*array_merge*` pero no se visaulizaba ningun dato en consola.

**1 Array questions (Aquí quiero agregar los datos del 2do Array)**

```
#items: array:2 [
    0 => {#2012
      +"question": "Como describirías un riesgo en la planta"
    }
    1 => {#2010
      +"question": "Si hubiera un incendio como reaccionarias?"
    }
  ]
```

**2 Array users**

```
0 => {#2008
      +"id": 7
      +"firstname": "Norma"
      +"lastname": "Molina"
    }
1 => {#2006
      +"id": 6
      +"firstname": "Rodrigo"
      +"lastname": "Sanchez"
    }
```

**Lo que intento hacer / expectativa:**

```
0 => {
    +"question": "Si hubiera un incendio como reaccionarias?"
    0 => {#2012
        +"id": 7
        +"firstname": "Norma"
        +"lastname": "Molina"
    }
    1 => {#2010
        +"id": 6
        +"firstname": "Rodrigo"
        +"lastname": "Sanchez"
    }
}
 1 => {
     +"question": "Como describirías un riesgo en la planta"
      0 => {#2012
        +"id": 7
        +"firstname": "Norma"
        +"lastname": "Molina"
    }
    1 => {#2010
        +"id": 6
        +"firstname": "Rodrigo"
        +"lastname": "Sanchez"
    }
}
```

La finalidad es que estén en un solo arreglo los 2 arrays, los usuarios serán siempre 2, por lo cual no import si se repiten, de hecho lo ocupo así y en cuanto a las preguntas esas pueden ser de 1 a muchos

**Actualización**
Agregue el indice '**users**' o lo que vendría hacer el índice **2** en el array questions; de esta manera es funcional

```
0 => {#2012
  +"question": "Como describirias un riesgo en la planta"
}
1 => {#2010
  +"question": "Si hubiera un incendio como reaccionarias?"
}
"users" =>  {#2013
  #items: array:2 [
    0 => {#2008
      +"id": 7
      +"firstname": "Norma"
      +"lastname": "Molina"
    }
    1 => {#2006
      +"id": 6
      +"firstname": "Rodrigo"
      +"lastname": "Sanchez"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: En la espectativa, te diría que le agregues una propiedad `users` a cada objeto de `questions`, y a esa  propiedad `users`  asignarle el array de objetos user. Que te quede algo así `[ 0 => {#2012 "question": "Si hubiera un incendio como reaccionarias?", "users": [ 0 => {#2008 "id": 7, "firstname": "Norma", "lastname": "Molina" }, 1 => {#2006 "id": 6, "firstname": "Rodrigo", "lastname": "Sanchez" } ] }, //... ]`

Comment: Actualizo, lo estaba haciendo similar solo que deje los deje fuera de las questions, dejando a 'users' como indice independiente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno pude solventar el problema, use un helper de Laravel similar al *array_push*, solo que en el helper defines la clave valor que quieres insertar en el array, en mi caso mi array tenia dos índices el *$questions[0]* & el *$questions[1](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers)*, decidí agregar de forma independiente uno índice más donde ingresaría los **usuarios** índice agregado: `$questions['users']`, dentro de este agregue los 2 índices de mis usuarios `$user[0]` & `$user[1]`;

La forma en que agregue el objeto $user al objeto $question:

Utilice el helper de Laravel `array_add` la manera en que funciona es similar a array_push, solo que en esté puedes definir la clave, valor a insertar ya sea posición que existe o una nueva;

Syntax example:

```
$array = array('foo' => 'bar');

$array = array_add($array, 'key', 'value');
```

Result:

```
array:2 [
  "foo" => "bar"
  "key" => "value"
]
```

Aplicado a mi problema:

```
$result =[];
$result = array_add($questions, 'users', $user);
```

Resultado obtenido:

```
    0 => {#2012
          +"question": "Como describirias un riesgo en la planta"
         }
    1 => {#2010
         +"question": "Si hubiera un incendio como reaccionarias?"
         }
    "users" => {#2013
      #items: array:2 [
        0 => {#2008
          +"id": 7
          +"firstname": "Norma"
          +"lastname": "Molina"
        }
        1 => {#2006
          +"id": 6
          +"firstname": "Rodrigo"
          +"lastname": "Sanchez"
        }
      ]
```

**ACTUALIZACION para poder empujar un nuevo elemento a un objeto de una manera más simple es la siguiente;**

Primero sabemos que Laravel nos devuelve un array [] y dentro de ese array tenemos un objeto: [ { } ] y a partir de ese objeto tenemos propiedades o llaves con sus valores:

```
 [ 'users' => {
    Nombre: 'John',
    Apellido: 'Doe'
    } 
 ]
```

Bien si quisiéramos agregar dentro del array users que tiene el objeto con propiedades Nombre, Apellido, quisieramos agregar question, como sería?

Puede ser de esta manera:

```
 $user[0]->question_1 = '';
```

Entonces aparecería como resultado de esta manera;

```
 [ 'users' => {
    Nombre: 'John',
    Apellido: 'Doe'
    question_1:''
    } 
 ]
```

[Más información de los helpers:](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers)